# uncertainties large from curve fit using a polynomial function

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

Using the following fitting procedure I want to fit a 2nd order polynomial to my data points. I have x, y and y_error points from my observations.

```
def fit(x,y,yerr):
  popt, pcov = curve_fit(func2,x,y,p0=[-0.6,5,-12],sigma=yerr,absolute_sigma=False)
  chi=np.sum( ((func2(x, *popt) - y) / yerr)**2)
  redchi=(chi-1)/len(y)
  a=len(y)
  print "chi= " + str(chi) + " for " + str(a) + " dof" + " redchi= " +str(redchi)
  return popt,pcov,redchi,len(y)

def func(x,a,b,c):
  return (a*(x**2)+b*x+c)

popt,pcov,chi,lenny=fit(x,y,yerr)
plt.plot(x,func2(x,*popt),c=c,linewidth=2)
```

So I'm simply using a least-squares method to fit this function. The values returned are the `a,b,c` parameters (`popt`) from the best fit and the covariance matrix (`pcov`) from the fitting.

I'm away that the standard errors for the parameters are the square roots of the diagonals from the covarance matrix: `a_err=np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))[0]` as `a=popt[0].`

However, the parameters don't seem independent and the covariance matrix has values outside the diagonal. Therefore (I think) this causes the parameter standard errors to be quite large.

From my fitting, the parameters I obtain are:

```
a=1.22731117 +/- 0.22210121
b=-11.31232672 +/- 2.01192621
c=43.6603686 +/- 4.53383215
```

The errors are quite large for the parameters! Once propagated through the polynomial function, the errors are large, and don't at all represent the errors from the fit. Below is the fitted values and the error region from the fit is shaded (ignore the lime green points), the red points and errors are my observed data and the thick red line is the fitted line, the shaded orange region is the 1 sigma error region.

[Fitted data, including error region.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9RJW.png)

Surely the true errors for the fit should be something like the residuals yfit-ydata or something. Can anybody help? I'm not sure how to calculate the errors for the fit in this instance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The main thing I would suggest is that you would be better to ask this question on http://stats.stackexchange.com/ because it's not essentially about programming, it's about statistics. 

It's not unusual for standard errors for parameters to be much larger than measurement error since they are, to some extent, a measure of the quality of fit of the model. In addition, if the model is 'correct' then one would expect the standard errors to become smaller with increased sample size. Your sample size is fairly small.

Comment: Are `yerr` measurement errors? If so, why do you use `absolute_sigma=False`? It should be `True` for measurement errors. (Check out my case study on that here: http://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sigma.html)

Comment: Thanks again tbuli :-)! I'll be happy once I've finished dealing with all the statistics in my work ;-).. it makes a difference when I set to True.

Comment: I think the problem lies with the fact I'm using log(time) on the x-axis so the model is fitting through the y-axis which is very far away from the data. I can get around this by fitting with 'x=x-np.mean(x)' this improves the covariance of b and c, which previously was the problem. Do you think this is statistically okay?

Comment: I don't think the errors in the parameters should change simply by shifting the x-axis. But it's because of the log scale. How did you calculate `yerr`? If I understand you correctly, `y=log(mag)`, `x=log(t)`. And the raw data is `mag +- mag_err` and `t`? If so, `yerr != log(mag_err)`. How did you calculate it, and is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Right yes, for errors I used yerr=1/ln(10) *(magerr/mag). Just from the usual error propagation. I guess it was the error on the offset, as this was far from the origin at zero. Therefore by shifting the error is improved and likewise the covariance between b,c is improved?

Comment: Ah yes, so that is correct. But I don't think you can just shift the x-axis since the size of the errors depends on the value of `mag` itself. And `x=log(t - np.mean(t))` is allowed but not x=x - np.mean(x). So let's approach this differently: is it not possible there is a strong correlation between the parameters? Why would the correlation be small? I agree the uncertainty in your fit looks a bit big but given that you tell scipy these are measurement errors it could very well be correct. How does the plot change with that option?